# how to fgrep/egrep exact string in a file

Tags: shell, unix, solaris, grep

I'm trying to search for an EXACT string match in a file. I know it can be done via "grep -w" but for some reason, i dont to do it with grep.

Already tried these and didnt work for me:

```
egrep '\< pattern \>' file
fgrep '\< pattern \>' file
egrep '^pattern$' file
fgrep '^pattern$' file
```

Example:

I want to display only the line that contains exactly the "ABC100-10" string

```
$ cat file
NULL1 VOID XX
NULL2 VOID XX
EMPTY VOID XX
ABC100-10 VOID XX
ABC100-102 VOID XX
```

When I try this:

```
egrep ABC100-10 file
```

Actual Output:

```
ABC100-10 VOID XX
ABC100-102 VOID XX
```

Expected output

```
ABC100-10 VOID XX
```

With word boundaries:

```
egrep '\<ABC100-10\>' file
```

No output. Expected output:

```
ABC100-10 VOID XX
```

With start/end of line boundaries:

```
egrep '^ABC100-10$' file
```

No output. Expected output:

```
ABC100-10 VOID XX
```

By the way, I'm using Solaris 8. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `\<` and `\>` can't have spaces after/before. Words by definition do not contain spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this okay ?

```
grep "\bABC100-10\b" file
```

You can use perl if grep works weird on Solaris

```
perl -ne 'print if /\bABC100-10\b/' file
```

\b indicates word boundary

Comment: The awk solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21388825/grep-awk-or-sed-print-lines-in-one-file-matching-patterns-in-another-file worked for me on Solaris with similar problem to yours, as long as I use "nawk" instead of plain "awk"

Answer (score 1):

`egrep` uses *regular expressions*, that is, backslashes, carets, dollar signs and other characters have special meanings. `fgrep` uses *literal strings*. To see the difference:

```
$ cd -- "$(mktemp --directory)" 
$ echo 'Bebop' > foo.txt
$ echo '$variable' > bar.txt
$ egrep '^Be' foo.txt || echo 'Not found'
Bebop
$ fgrep '^Be' foo.txt || echo 'Not found'
Not found
$ egrep '$var' bar.txt || echo 'Not found'
Not found
$ fgrep '$var' bar.txt || echo 'Not found'
$variable
```

If this isn't clear, please provide the actual commands and contents of `file`, the results, and what you expected to see instead.

**Update**: By default, any `grep` will print every line where the pattern matches *anywhere on the line*. `grep` doesn't do word searches like Google, it just looks for strings. So if you want to search for the *word* `ABC100-10` you'll need to use `egrep '\<ABC100-10\>'` (as you tried) or `egrep '\bABC100-10\b'`. I think you must be using a `grep` version which doesn't support `\<` and `\>`, because here it works as expected.

`^` and `$` denote the start and end of *line*, respectively, so they will only print lines which contain *only* the string between them. For example, to search for an empty line, you could use `egrep '^$'`.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. i have updated the question for the expected result

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the problem is really in the version I'm using.