# Print lines in one file matching patterns in another file

Tags: unix, sed, awk, grep, extract

I have a file with more than 40.000 lines (file1) and I want to extract the lines matching patterns in file2 (about 6000 lines). I use grep like this, but it is very slow:

```
grep -f file2 file1 > out
```

Is there a faster way to do this using `awk` or `sed`?

Here's some extracts from my files:

`File1`:

```
scitn003869.2| scign003869 CGCATGTGTGCATGTATTATCGTATCCCTTG
scitn007747.1| scign007747  CACGCAGACGCAGTGGAGCATTCCAGGTCACAA
scitn003155.1| scign003155  TAAAAATCGTTAGCACTCGCTTGGTACACTAAC
scitn018252.1| scign018252  CGTGTGTGTGCATATGTGTGCATGCGTG
scitn004671.2| scign004671  TCCTCAGGTTTTGAAAGGCAGGGTAAGTGCT
```

`File2`:

```
scign000003
scign000004
scign000005
scign004671
scign000013
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try `grep -Fwf file2 file1 > out`

The `-F` option specifies plain string matching, so should be faster without having to engage the regex engine.

Comment: This job took only about a second!

Comment: Fgrep is this native option equivalent and maybe still few msec faster

Comment: my grep man page says: "fgrep is the
       same as grep -F.  Direct invocation as either egrep or fgrep is deprecated, ..."

Answer (score 15):

Here's how to do it in awk:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{pats[$0]; next} $2 in pats' File2 File1
```

Using a 60,000 line File1 (your File1 repeated 8000 times) and a 6,000 File2 (yours repeated 1200 times):

```
$ time grep -Fwf File2 File1 > ou2

real    0m0.094s
user    0m0.031s
sys     0m0.062s

$ time awk 'NR==FNR{pats[$0]; next} $2 in pats' File2 File1 > ou1

real    0m0.094s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.077s

$ diff ou1 ou2
```

i.e. it's about as fast as the grep. One thing to note though is that the awk solution lets you pick a specific field to match on so if anything from File2 shows up anywhere else in File1 you won't get a false match. It also lets you match on a whole field at a time so if your target strings were various lengths and you didn't want "scign000003" to match "scign0000031" for example (though the -w for grep gives similar protection for that).

For completeness, here's the timing for the other awk solution posted elsethread:

```
$ time awk 'BEGIN{i=0}FNR==NR{a[i++]=$1;next}{for(j=0;j<i;j++)if(index($0,a[j]))print $0}' File2 File1 > ou3

real    3m34.110s
user    3m30.850s
sys     0m1.263s
```

and here's the timing I get for the perl script Mark posted:

```
$ time ./go.pl > out2

real    0m0.203s
user    0m0.124s
sys     0m0.062s
```

Comment: Whilst this may do what the OP meant and wanted, and I do see you alluded to that and portrayed it as a benefit of avoiding false matches, the OP should be aware that it doesn't actually do the same as his code. His code will find matches anywhere on the line, whereas yours will only find matches in the second field.

Answer (score 6):

You could try with this awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{i=0}
FNR==NR { a[i++]=$1; next }
{ for(j=0;j<i;j++)
    if(index($0,a[j]))
        {print $0;break}
}' file2 file1
```

The `FNR==NR` part specifies that the stuff following it in curly braces is only to be applied when processing the first input file (`file2`).  And it says to save all the words you are looking for in an array `a[]`. The bit in the second set of curly braces applies to the processing of the second file... as each line is read in, it is compared with all elements of `a[]` and if any are found, the line is printed. That's all folks!

Comment: Works perfect. And much much faster than my grep command. Thanks!

Comment: You'll gain some efficiency with `if (index($0, a[j]) {print; break}`

Comment: Good thinking, Glenn. Thank you.

Comment: and can still optimize if you sort the files (especioally if one is nearly everytime the same at runtime, i guess file2 here)

Answer (score 5):

Just for fun, here's a Perl version:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my %patterns;
my $srch;

# Open file and get patterns to search for
open(my $fh2,"<","file2")|| die "ERROR: Could not open file2";
while (<$fh2>)
{
   chop;
   $patterns{$_}=1;
}

# Now read data file
open(my $fh1,"<","file1")|| die "ERROR: Could not open file1";
while (<$fh1>)
{
   (undef,$srch,undef)=split;
   print $_ if defined $patterns{$srch};
}
```

Here are some timings, using a 60,000 line file1 and 6,000 line file2 per Ed's file creation method:

```
time awk 'NR==FNR{pats[$0]; next} $2 in pats' file2 file1 > out
real    0m0.202s
user    0m0.197s
sys     0m0.005s

time ./go.pl > out2
real    0m0.083s
user    0m0.079s
sys     0m0.004s
```

Comment: +1 Nice one. Wonder why this is more than twice as fast as the `awk` solution.. By the way, I assume you saved the output of the perl program also to a file? (There is no redirection after `./go.pl` in you answer)

Comment: It my "best" Perl and I did take advantage of everything I knew about the data, like using chop() and then (undef, $srch,undef) to discard stuff I didn't need and awk doesn't have that luxury. I did save it to a file but only copied and pasted the timings rather than having to edit out my prompt.

Comment: The measurements I got were completely the opposite of the above (see my updated post) with the perl ending up twice as slow as awk or grep. I suspect Mark didn't run the script a few times to account for caching before taking his timing.

Comment: How odd! I did run them both several times and they were pretty consistent on my Mac - and it runs off a SSD which normally makes timing consistent - having no rotational delays or seek times.

Comment: idk. I find perl a tad hard to read to say the least but it LOOKS like it's doing the same thing that my awk script does, just with hand-written loops and splitting of the line into fields, so I'd expect the perl to maybe be a bit slower just due to having to hand-write the loop/split code vs using built-in functionality but I'd expect the 2 scripts to be about in the same ball-park. I suppose when you're talking about .1 vs .2 secs that is about in the same ball-park vs some of the other solutions in the order of minutes.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the sake of learning: I was solving the same problem and I came up with various solutions (including `read $line` loops etc..). When I got to the `grep` one-liner found above, I still ended up getting the wrong output. Then I realized my PATTERN file had 2 trailing lines... So `grep` picked up all my lines from my database. Morality: **check you trailing spaces/lines**. Also, ran the command on a much larger dataset with several hundreds patterns and `time` couldn't even count.

Comment: Ugh, thank you so much! I was wondering why it looked like my whole file returned

Comment: `grep -Fwf <(grep '[^[:blank]]' file2) file1` will include only lines containing a non-blank character.

Comment: I will add that if you have a "blacklist" and you want everything that is not in the file2, then you simply add `-v` like so: `grep -vFwf file2 file1 > out`