# Linux Compare two text files

Tags: linux, shell

I have two text file like below:

**File1.txt**

```
A|234-211
B|234-244
C|234-351
D|999-876
E|456-411
F|567-211
```

**File2.txt**

```
234-244
999-876
567-211
```

And I want to compare both files and get containing values like below:

**Dequired output**

```
B|234-244
D|999-876
F|567-211
```

Comment: `diff File1.txt File2.txt`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [grep, awk or sed? Print lines in one file matching patterns in another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21388825/grep-awk-or-sed-print-lines-in-one-file-matching-patterns-in-another-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ grep -F -f file2.txt file1.txt
B|234-244
D|999-876
F|567-211
```

The `-F` makes grep search for fixed strings (not patterns). Both `-F` and `-f` are [POSIX options](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) to `grep`.

Note that this assumes your `file2.txt` does not contain short strings like `11` which could lead to false positives.

Comment: not working only return F|567-211

Comment: @Kavinda Yes, it is working. The output shown is exactly my result for your specified input files. Cut and paste my command into your command line and you can verify. If it is not working for you, your input files are not what you have shown us.

Comment: Thank you very much  working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
grep -f File2.txt File1.txt
```

Comment: not working only return F|567-211