# retain rows only when column has certain values in a file

Tags: awk, sed

I have the a file where I need to retain rows if first column value is equal to brand,city and zipcode
So for this file

```
    product,0 0,no way
    brand,0 0 0,detergent
    product,0 0 1,sugar
    negative,0 0 1, sight
    city,0 0 2,grind
    zipcode,0 0 1,five
```

I will need this output

```
brand,0 0 0,detergent
city,0 0 2,grind
zipcode,0 0 1,five
```

What is the efficient way to accomplish this if the number  of retained values increase say from 3 here to 20-30? Can we use a file values.txt that has the values we need to retain

```
   brand
   city
   zipcode
```

which can be used?

Comment: Do the files have the leading spaces that you are showing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print lines in one file matching patterns in another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21388825/print-lines-in-one-file-matching-patterns-in-another-file)

Answer (score 3):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{v[$1]; next} $1 in v' values.txt FS=, datafile
```

Comment: Does not seem to work for me. Gives me an empty file.

Comment: do the records have the leading space as you posted?  This script assumes they don't.  Also fixed a typo, should check for the array `v` not `a`.

Comment: No leading space.

Answer (score 0):

Keep lines where the first record matches brand, city or zipcode:

awk

```
awk -F, '$1~/^(brand|city|zipcode)$/' file
```

sed

```
sed -r '/^(brand|city|zipcode),/!d' file
```

awk reading definitions from file

```
awk -F, 'a[$1];FNR==NR{a[$1]=1}' values.txt file
```

This requires unique values in `values.txt`.

Comment: That last one is fragile as it'll behave undesirably (by a reasonable expectation of requirements) if values.txt contains the same value twice. The 1st and 2nd ones will fail if `file` starts with `intercity` or other partial matches are present.

Comment: @EdMorton Yes, I indeed thought of that when I wrote it. But since you see it immediately (the output *starts* with lines from `values.txt` - and they are in a different format). I definitely agree on the other two and made the changes. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure we're talking about the same thing with that awk script. Regardless of order and format, if `values.txt` contains `x` twice then `x` will be printed when the 2nd `x`-line is read - that's my concern. You could move the `,` outside of the parens in the sed script btw.

Comment: @EdMorton Yes, that's what I meant. The output will contain `x` (and all the other duplicates or triplicates) and then the script will print the matching lines from file, like `product,0 0,no way`.

Comment: @EdMorton Yep, I've moved them outside, now that I have my parens ;-)

Comment: The two different  solutions (`awk`, `sed`) compared to the OP are non-scalable without making the entire thing ugly, which is especially what the asker wants, where one expects more than 30 variables.

Answer (score 0):

Grep is a lot easier for this application. Just create a file named "words" containing each word you're interested in on a separate line. Then:

```
cat words | while read interesting_word; do grep "^$interesting_word" myfile; done
```